# Catch Facebook friend email-id in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to catch facebook friends email-id through the programmatically?

I have use below graph API for this but i did not received friend email-id?
https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=%@

Comment: Facebook graph api not give friends email id..

Comment: Facebook doesn't provide Friends email id while fetching their data.

Comment: Otherwise it would be "heaven for phishing and spamming"! Don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email permission is only for the logged_in user
There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends. from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)